# Logic error when checking if input is alphanumeric

Tags: c++, alphanumeric

The purpose of this program is to check if the character entered by the user is alphanumeric. Once the void function confirms correct entry then it is passed to string test to output a message. I know it's not great coding but it has to be done this way.

I keep getting a logic error & I can't figure out why?  Can someone please help?

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

void get_option(char& input);
/**
Takes character entered user input and loops until correct answer
@param y character entered by user
@return to main() once valid entry received
*/
string test(char);
/**
Takes checks character entered user input and loops until correct answer
@param y alphanumeric character entered by user
@return to main() once valid entry received
*/

int main()
{
    char y;

    //call get_option to prompt for input
    get_option(y);
    //call test after user input is valid
    test(y);

    return 0;
}

void get_option(char &x)
    {

        cout << "Please enter an alphanumeric character: ";
        cin >> x;

        while (!(isdigit(x)||islower(x)||isupper(x)))
        {
            cout << "Please enter an alphanumeric character: ";
            cin >> x;
        }
    }    

string test(char y)
    {
        if (isupper(y))
        {
            cout << "An upper case letter is entered!";
            } else if (islower(y)) { 
                cout << "A lower case letter is entered!";
                } else if (isdigit(y)) {
                cout << "A digit is entered!";
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: Why do you declare `test` as returning a `string`, then return `0` (not a string) from it, and then ignore its return value altogether?

Comment: There is something called `isalpha()`. Also, functions like `isalpha()` technically have undefined behavior if you use a `char` as an input since it expects `unsigned char`s. You should cast it to an unsigned char first. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit

Comment: Better yet, [std::isalnum()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalnum) checks for alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 1):

I got the program to work perfectly by changing the return type of the `test(char)` function:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

void get_option(char& input);
/**
Takes character entered user input and loops until correct answer
@param y character entered by user
@return to main() once valid entry received
*/
int test(char); //Changed from string to int
/**
Takes checks character entered user input and loops until correct answer
@param y alphanumeric character entered by user
@return to main() once valid entry received
*/

int main()
{
    char y;

    //call get_option to prompt for input
    get_option(y);
    //call test after user input is valid
    test(y);

    return 0;
}

void get_option(char &x)
    {

        cout << "Please enter an alphanumeric character: ";
        cin >> x;

        while (!(isdigit(x)||islower(x)||isupper(x)))
        {
            cout << "Please enter an alphanumeric character: ";
            cin >> x;
        }
    }    

int test(char y) //Also changed from string to int
    {
        if (isupper(y))
        {
            cout << "An upper case letter is entered!";
            } else if (islower(y)) { 
                cout << "A lower case letter is entered!";
                } else if (isdigit(y)) {
                cout << "A digit is entered!";
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

(Testing was on [JDoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-compiler-c++14) using the C++14 compiler.)
(Also, tested using Xcode. Still works)

Answer (score 0):

When I tried it in my setup (g++ 6.4, cygwin), I did not get any output. When I added `<< endl` to the output lines, the output showed up.

I suspect you're experiencing the same problem.

```
string test(char y)
{
   if (isupper(y))
   {
      cout << "An upper case letter is entered!" << endl;  // Add endl
   }
   else if (islower(y))
   { 
      cout << "A lower case letter is entered!" << endl;
   }
   else if (isdigit(y))
   {
      cout << "A digit is entered!" << endl;
   }

   // This does not make sense but it is syntactically valid.
   return 0;
}
```

---

[JiveDadson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/445296/jive-dadson) is right. The problem was the `return 0` line. It causes undefined behavior. Changing the that line to

```
return "";
```

fixes the output problem, `endl` or not. Having the `endl` is nicer but is not necessary. Fixing the `return` statement is the most important task.